# Whitespaces with echo (php)

Tags: php, whitespace

I have a whitespace issue, when I echo something from the database into a textarea it adds some whitespaces.

when I use trim() it only removes the whitespaces at the beginning but there are still some left. I just can't wrap my head around it.

```
echo trim("[quote=".name($msg['naam'])."]\n".$msg['bericht']."[/quote]\n");
```

I load the quoted message with jQuery like this

```
function quoteMessage(pid){
    $("#post2").addClass("click");
    $(".label").addClass("hidden");
    $.post('/action-handler.php', { action: 'quote_message', pid: pid}, function(response) {
        if(response != 'ERR'){
            $('#post2').val($('#post2').val()+response);
        } else {
            $('#response').css('display', 'block');
            $("#response").append("<p class='good display-error'>An unexpected error occurred.</p>");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only remove the `\n` at the end?

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: Then, what is your html element with the id `#post2`? `/action-handler.php` return the echo you written?

Comment: `<textarea name="post2" class="tbox" id="post2"></textarea>` and yes `/action-handler.php` returns the echo

Comment: Could you paste (by checking with firebug for example) the html generated after the textarea is filled?

Comment: It just puts it in the textarea, jQuery doesn't change the html at all.

Comment: it doesn't change the html but it put some data into the textarea

Comment: That's correct, it adds the text as if its written in the area. Like this reply box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure, your html code is like this :

```
<textarea>

<?php echo $value ?>

</textarea>
```

Then you have white space inside your textarea. You should write:

```
<textarea><?php echo $value ?></textarea>
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YaSzn/).

Comment: I fetch it in jQuery 
I'll put the code in the main Question. This looks messy.

Answer (score 0):

You could regex to remove extra whitespace?

```
 $no_whitespace = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value);
```

This will turn all whitespace into a single space.